# What do I need to manipulate in GIMP to follow these specific color patterns I'm working with?

Tags: color, gimp, png, patterns, hex

I am using GIMP and my images are appearing darker in an app I'm using, specifically OOTP 18.

For example, my blue `#0054a4` displays as a darker blue `#003184`, when I need it to appear as blue `#004295` to match the blue in the game. There is a consistent pattern happening for all colors, but I don't know what exactly I need to manipulate on GIMP.

Here is an example of what's happening to my colors from lightest to darkest:

- RED: png file color `#CE1041` → file stores as `#C40930` → display result `#B90421`,

  and then...
- BROWN: `#965C0E` → `#854907` → `#733703`
- BLUE: `#0054A4` → `#004295` → `#003184`

I need to figure out what I need to manipulate, or what is a common pattern between these colors to have the next lightest set of colors to match the other similar images in the game. The built-in images in the game are proprietary, and therefore can't be viewed or opened. I only use GIMP and Mac Preview, unless anyone can recommend another free editor that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a gamma mismatch problem. Two things to try:

1. `Edit>Preferences>Color management`, and `Mode of operation: no color management`
2. `View>Display filters`,

   - add the Gamma filter (move from left panel to right)
   - set a gamma value less than one, to darken what you see in Gimp

Solution 1) can also be tested with 2) (there is a filter that corresponds to it). Also filters apply to the view, so you can use `View>New view` to create a second display of the same image, and apply the Gamma filter in it. You can then work on the usual display, while at the same time seeing how it will look in the game.